# How to pass commas which separates variables into a bash script?

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

**Ubuntun 16.04

Bash 4.4.0**

I have lines and lines in a csv file that I can use as variables. Example:

```
"2013","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
"2014","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
"2012","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
"2011","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
```

I want to pass these lines into a bash script that will generate a complete url.

```
Example: bash scriptname.sh "2012","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
```

I can replace spaces that are within the variables from inside the script. How can I strip the commas that separate the variables being passed to the script, inside the script, before they interact and set themselves.

Here's an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

year="${1}"
oinker="${2// /%20}"
poinker="${3// /%20}"
loinker="${4// /%20}"

echo "https://mickeyorileysooo.com/sysbuilder.php?bg=2&year=${year}&oinker=${oinker}&poinker=${poinker}&loinker=${loinker}"
```

Here is the result:

```
root@0000 ~ # bash scriptname.sh "2012" "White Woman" "Green Orcas Rolling" "Felix"
https://mickeyorileysooo.com/sysbuilder.php?bg=2&year=2012&oinker=White%20Woman&poinker=Green%20Orcas%20Rolling&loinker=Felix
```

Here is an updated script with guidance from Barmar:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
set -- $*

year="${1}"
oinker="${2// /%20}"
poinker="${3// /%20}"
loinker="${4// /%20}"

echo "https://mickeyorileysooo.com/sysbuilder.php?bg=2&year=${year}&oinker=${oinker}&poinker=${poinker}&loinker=${loinker}"
```

Now I leave the commas on the command line and run the script:

```
root@0000 ~ # bash scriptname.sh "2012","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"
https://mickeyorileysooo.com/sysbuilder.php?bg=2&year=2012&oinker=White%20Woman&poinker=Green%20Orcas%20Rolling&loinker=Felix
```

The commas are now gone and the result is perfect!

```
https://mickeyorileysooo.com/sysbuilder.php?bg=2&year=2012&oinker=White%20Woman&poinker=Green%20Orcas%20Rolling&loinker=Felix
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. The argument to `bash` should be the name of a script.

Comment: I corrected it all. I updated my post.

Comment: How does the CSV file fit into this? Are the arguments being entered by hand on the command line, or being read from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use comma as the delimiter in the script instead of space, set the variable `IFS`.

```
IFS=,
set -- $*
```

After this, `$1` will be `2012`, `$2` will be `White Woman`, `$3` will be `Green Orcas Rolling`, and `$4` will be `Felix`.

Comment: That is not working correctly. The variables are wrapped with double-quotes. so I made ```IFS=,`` to be ```IFS=","``` and that did not work either. I Appreciate the help.

Comment: I thought the quotes were on the command line, I forgot that this is being read from a file.

Comment: ```bash scriptname.sh "2012","White Woman","Green Orcas Rolling","Felix"``` so I will be placing this on the command line and hitting enter.

Comment: If you place that on the command line, the shell removes the quotes before calling the script.

Comment: But if you read the line from a file, and then use `bash scriptname.sh "$line"` the quotes are not removed.

Comment: I updated my OP. See if this make sense. I need to do a better job with my question it seems.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, I shouldn't quote `$*`, since that prevents IFS from splitting it.

Comment: That was the ticket there. It is now working perfectly. But, take a good look at my question and script. It boggles my mind why you deemed this question to have been already answered in another thread. But so be it. I just hope this helps someone else. I definitely appreciate the time you took to help.

Comment: The question starts by saying that you have these lines in a CSV file that you want to split into fields. Everything else in the question seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I don't remember posting anything like that. If you review my edit history, the original first line says: ```I have lines and lines of 4 variables in a csv files that I can quickly pass into a bash script that will generate a complete url.```
I did not change my first line until today. Even with the information I had in my original statement, I don't see the correlation between the 2 threads. I'm just trying to understand this so I don't repeat my mistake.